# How does i execute Cron job using browse direct URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

My application run on hostgater.com .
i created a Cron job scheduler in my server and set all those parameters.

it working good far

```
command parameter like /home3/user/public_html/sendemial.php.
```

it is not workging i try to execute the MVC controller action URL like

```
command parameter like http://voola.org/user/sendemail
```

i also tried to using iframe, but it is  not workin. i am very worry about to execute direct url in Hostgater server.

any help will be appreciate :)

Comment: Your best bet here is to use a command line utility like wget to fetch the url or create a php file that loads the url via curl or file_get_contents

Comment: Thanks for technique @Orangepill, i will implement?

Comment: by the way it has been working charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

examoleThanks @Orangepill, you are great. using curl its working charm. below is my code example

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sadf/profiles/emailalert");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result=curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
if($result){
    echo "execute by curl ok and sending mail";
}else{
    echo "not execute curl funation";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual for running from command line:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html